# VBA vlookup getting the data from closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I trying to use the vlookup below to get data from a close workbook, most likely I am missing some ampersands, but now sure where. Any suggestion?

```
ws1.Cells(r, c).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Vlkup & ",'" & path & "[01_Coles_Scan_Sales_All.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E:$O,11,0)"
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")

    Dim LRow As Integer
    LRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    
    Dim LCol As Integer
    LCol = ws1.Cells(5, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Dim VlkupRng As Range
    Set VlkupRng = ws1.Range("A5", ws1.Cells(LRow, LCol))
      
    Dim path As String 'Getting Scan data
    path = "\\bfgfs\Supply Chain\Demand Planning\Coles\Promo Review Report\"
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim Vlkup As Variant
    
    For r = 6 To VlkupRng.Rows.Count
        
        For c = 6 To VlkupRng.Columns.Count
        
        Vlkup = ws1.Cells(r, 2) & ws1.Cells(r, 5) & Format(ws1.Cells(5, c), "d/mm/yyyy")
        
            If Cells(r, 5).Value = "Coles Scan Sales" Then
                ws1.Cells(r, c).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Vlkup & ",'" & path & "[01_Coles_Scan_Sales_All.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E:$O,11,0)"
            End If
    
        Next c
        
    Next r
 
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Vlkup` variable returns something that seems like a string (not sure). Maybe check that and see if it is a string, surround it with quotes.

Comment: ^^^ that would be `... = "=VLOOKUP(""" & Vlkup & """,'" & ...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem I see is that variable `Vlookup` is a Variant type and the `Vlookup` formula needs it to be a string type so I suggest the formula to use the `CStr()` convertion that is like this:

```
ws1.Cells(r, c).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & CStr(Vlkup) & ",'" & path & "[01_Coles_Scan_Sales_All.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E:$O,11,0)"
```

Hope it works cause I can't see any other problem.